# How to log deleted images with a discord bot

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I have been spending hours trying to get this code to log deleted images but everything I have tried its been nothing but fails, it logs deleted messages but images it just ignores completely.

Can someone please point me in the right direction on how to fix this issue, please. Any help is very much appreciated

```
const Discord = require('discord.js')
module.exports = async (client, message) => {

    if (!message.guild) return;
    if (!message.content) return;
    const logs = message.guild.channels.find(c => c.name === '420-logs');

    if (!logs) {
        return console.log(`[WARN]: The Delete Logs channel does not exist in the server named '${message.guild.name}'`)
    }

    if (message.attachments.size > 0) { // If I change this to: message.attachments.size>0 && message it works with deleted image & text but as it is without this said line it doesn't function

        var Attachment = (message.attachments).array();

        Attachment.forEach(function(attachment) {
            const logembed = new Discord.RichEmbed()

                .setAuthor(message.author.tag, message.author.displayAvatarURL)
                .setDescription(`**Image sent by ${message.author.tag} deleted in <#${message.channel.id}>**`)
                .setImage(attachment.proxyURL)

                .setColor(message.guild.member(client.user).displayHexColor)

                .setFooter(`Deleted Image`)
                .setTimestamp()

            logs.send(logembed);
            console.log(attachment.proxyURL);
        })
    } else {
        const logembed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
            //.setTitle('Message Deleted')
            .setAuthor(message.author.tag, message.author.displayAvatarURL)
            .setDescription(`**Message sent by ${message.author.tag} deleted in <#${message.channel.id}>**`)
            .addField("Message Content", `${message.content}`)

            .setColor(message.guild.member(client.user).displayHexColor)

            .setFooter(`Deleted Message`)
            .setTimestamp()

        logs.send(logembed);

    }
}
```

Comment: I see you're logging the `.proxyURL`: if you go to that URL with the browser, does it display your image? Also, have you tried using `.url` instead?

Comment: I have used .url that didnt work.
@FedericoGrandi

Comment: I see you're logging the `.proxyURL`: if you go to that URL with the browser, does it display your image?

Comment: @FedericoGrandi i did that but again it still doesnt log

Comment: Ok. Why are you saying `var Attachment = (message.attachments).array();`? In the next line you use `Attachement.forEach()` but that's not an Array method. Try using `message.attachments.forEach()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

So far you can't. When a member deletes a message, sure it does return all the stuff for a message with attachment links and all, but when that image is deleted the URL returned is useless because it references an image that doesn't exist on the Discord servers. If you open the link in a web browser it will say this:
[image: Error]